# What is in a boiling bubble of water-?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I don't know what is in a boiling water bubble and that is why I asked

Comment: Steam/"water vapor"

Comment: I know it is hot, I also know the pressure in the bubble is greater than the surrounding water pressure but still I do not know the vis inside the bubble pushing the water away. I liked your answer but there is more to this or so it seems

Answer (score 2):

The bubbles rising up in vigorously boiling water consist of water vapor, and a tiny amount of air.

At the temperature of boiling water, the pressure exerted by the water vapor equals the pressure exerted by the atmosphere plus the hydrostatic pressure exerted by the water. This keeps the bubbles inflated as they rise.

Comment: Where does the air come from? Is that dissolved in water or something?

Comment: yes, it comes out of solution when the water boils.

Comment: there must be more to it than that, there must/is